# Change value of array given as parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I try to change a struct into a byte array in a function. I want to give the function a char pointer as a parameter and want to change the value of this pointer to point to the new array. This works in the function, but outside the pointer points to a random number.

This is how my function looks like:

```
void getNewMessage(char *bit_struct, size_t *msglen) {
    Pos struct_data = {0, 0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 100.0};
    *msglen = sizeof(struct_data);
    char b[*msglen];
    memcpy(b, &bit_struct, *msglen);
    bit_struct = b;

    // Recreate the struct to check
    Pos tmp;
    memcpy(&tmp, bit_struct, sizeof(tmp));
    std::cout << "struct in function is: " << tmp.posX << std::endl;
}
```

If I recreate the struct in the function it's fine. If I create it outside using the pointer I gave as a parameter the value is wrong.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like C but it isnt. Why dont you use containers instead of raw arrays?

Comment: I want to send the bytearray via a udp connection later on, thus a container would just increase the size of data I have to send. So I stick with a simple byte array.

Comment: `memcpy(b, &bit_struct, *msglen);` doesn't do what you think it does. Did you mean to write `memcpy(b, bit_struct, *msglen);`?

Comment: " thus a container would just increase the size of data I have to send" no. it would make your code much "nicer" (easier to read and less error prone) and when it comes to sending the data you dont have to send the container but only the raw array. You can always get a raw array from a vector or vice versa, so there is really no reason to deal with raw arrays everywhere just because you need a raw array in one place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bit_struct = b;` won't work. change `getNewMessage(char *bit_struct, size_t *msglen)` to `getNewMessage(char*& bit_struct, size_t *msglen)`

Comment: I totally forgot about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
char b[*msglen];
```

This will create a local array, meaning it will go out of scope once you leave the function. Its contents are then undefined.

What you want to do is

```
char* b = (char*) malloc(*msglen);
```

in C, or

```
char* b = new char[*msglen];
```

in C++.

Don't forget to free or delete[] *bit_struct* before you assign *b* to it, as it will cause memory leak.

As a side note,

```
char b[*msglen];
```

arrays of variable length are not legal in C++.

Comment: It's a while since I worked with pointers. 'malloc/new' solves part of the problem